# Field Update in Workflow Rule

Tags: workflowrule

I need to set a field on the `Order` object using a `Workflow Field Update`, and the updated value should be formatted as follows:

```
<Account JDE Ship to number> - YYMMDDHHmmSS
```

I have tried to the following formula:

```
Account.JDE_ship_to_account_no__c - DATETIMEVALUE()
```

But the formula editor gives me this error:

> Error: Incorrect number of parameters for function 'DATETIMEVALUE()'.` Expected 1, received 0

How can I make this field update work?

Comment: Where does the date you want to put in there come from?

Comment: What is `Account JDE Shipto number`? Do you want your field to look like `XX999 - YYMMDDHHmmSS`, assuming XX999 is your `Account JDE Shipto number` and YYMMDDHHmmSS a date/time stamp of last value update on some field?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use something like the one here:

> Formula

```
Account.JDE_ship_to_account_no__c + '-' + 
Right( Text( Year( Today() ) ), 2) + 
Lpad( Text( Month( Today() )), 2, '0' ) + 
Lpad( Text( Day( Today() )), 2, '0' ) + 
SUBSTITUTE(Left( Right( Text( Now() ), 9), 8), ':', '')
```

> Result

[image]

> Warning!

Don't be scared, just note that the time part will return the value in **GMT** not in your local time. Details and some very useful tips on working with date-time formulas can be found [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=formula_using_date_datetime.htm&language=en_US&type=0).

Comment: I have but I suggest you contact the SFSE meta for the same as well. They might have a better solution for you.

Comment: please see this http://meta.salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/2473/salesforce-stackexchange-unable-to-ask-question?noredirect=1#comment2487_2473

Comment: Yes, you can create a [Process Builder](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=process_overview.htm&type=0) or an [Apex trigger](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers.htm).

Answer (score 2):

> DATETIMEVALUE
>
> Use: DATETIMEVALUE(expression) and replace expression with a
>   date/time or text value, merge field, or expression.Description:  Returns a year, month, day and GMT time

[Link to documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=customize_functions_a_h.htm&type=0&language=en_US)

Field Name & '-' & YYYYMMDDHHSS

Y know how to print the YYYYMMDD but i'm not sure how to print the hours and seconds on an easy way since there on build in function yet :

You can check more discussion about that here:
https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000008v7gIAA

For YYYYMMDD assuming you always want 2 digits on MM & DD I would use :

```
TEXT(YEAR(DATEVALUE(NOW()))) & IF(LEN(TEXT(MONTH(DATEVALUE(NOW()))))=1,'0'&TEXT(MONTH(DATEVALUE(NOW()))),TEXT(MONTH(DATEVALUE(NOW())))) & IF(LEN(TEXT(DAY(DATEVALUE(NOW()))))=1,'0'&TEXT(DAY(DATEVALUE(NOW()))),TEXT(DAY(DATEVALUE(NOW()))))
```

But probably there are more elegant ways of doing it.

Comment: How to add the field as before , that field is in Number data type

Comment: but you guided thank you but i want this format YYMMDDHHmmSS

Answer (score 1):

**DATETIMEVALUE()** expect a parameter Date as as String to convert to a date

Example :

```
DATETIMEVALUE("2005-11-15 17:00:00")
```

To get the current timestamp use the function **NOW()**